# What does "covariance risk budget" mean in fPortfolio package?

Tags: r, optimization, finance

I have been using the fPortfolio package and have found some inconsistency in the usage of terminology in the package.

What does a "covariance risk budget" in the result returned by mean variance portfolio optimization- mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a presentation of RMetrics team it seems to be the derivative of the weight with respect to the standard-deviation, normalized by the standard-deviation. More formally:

$$\sigma = \sqrt{w^T\hat{\Sigma}w}=\sum_i w_i \frac{d \sigma}{d w_i}$$

$$1=\sum_i \mathscr{B}_i=\sum_i \frac{w_i}{\sigma} \frac{d \sigma}{d w_i}$$